# Correct path/url for media files in django

Tags: python, css, django, assets

I am using django 1.5.2 and I am having a hard time understanding the purpose of the media directory vs. the static directory and how to include stylesheets in my django project.

This is my directory structure:

```
django_books
    beer
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        views.py
    random_book
        (same as beer above)
    django_books (the actual django project; beer and random_book above are my apps)
        templates
            base.html
            beersall.html
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        wsgi.py
        static
            css
                beers.css
    media
        css
            beers.css
    static
        css
            beers.css
    manage.py
```

My beersall.html template (the beer output is correct, so just linking the stylesheet is wrong):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <div id="beer_list">
        {% for beer in beers %}
        {{ beer }},
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

My base.html file:

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/beers.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/beers.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/beers.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/beers.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/username/Projects/django_books/media/beers.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/username/Projects/django_books/static/beers.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/static/beers.css" />

    {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page_container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My settings.py file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/username/Projects/django_books/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/Users/username/Projects/django_books/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I should note that I am using the django development server, not apache.

The error in my browser (developer console) says `beers.css` is 404.

The url is `localhost:8000/beers/` and my urls.py file correctly points to this and the views.py correctly serves the beersall.html template. How can I properly link my media?

### EDIT

When I change the css link href value to `/Users/username/Projects/django_books/media/` it still doesn't work.

### EDIT 2

I've updated the `href` values to show things I've tried. Still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static files were being found, but the permissions were not set up correctly. (i.e. a 403 not a 404 server error)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/django.wsgi

    #the directory tag before was /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/>
    #this was one directory too deep
    #from my structure above, you can see I needed to change my directory tag to this:

    <Directory /Users/username/Projects/django_books/>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /Users/username/.virtualenvs/django_books/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/admin/ /Users/username/.virtualenvs/django_books/lib/python2.7/site-packages/d$
    Alias /static/ /Users/username/Projects/django_books/static/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The first `Alias` directive solved the next problem I had, which was my admin css not working. I had to include that, then place it before the other `Alias` that was overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

User-uploaded files (by admins or site users) go to media directory.
Static files are files provided by developers (or from third-party apps).

Set something like this:

```
# Local disk paths
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/username/Projects/django_books/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/username/Projects/django_books/static/'

# URLs visible in the browser's address bar
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And in Your template use the `STATIC_URL` variable:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/beers.css" />
```

And move your styles to the `django_books/static/` directory.

Comment: The `{{ STATIC_URL }}` adds just '/static/' to the href attribute. It doesn't use the static root. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, `STATIC_URL` adds just  '/static/' to URL in rendered HTML. To tell Django, where on local disk look for files use the `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATICFILES_FINDERS` settings. See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-dirs

Answer (score 0):

in my project:[django_learn](https://github.com/thinker3/django_learn), in template: [check_uncheck_all.html](https://github.com/thinker3/django_learn/blob/master/learn/templates/learn/check_uncheck_all.html), part pf the code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <script type=text/javascript src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.9.1.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
```

you can also have a look at my settings.py